# Reading all the events happened during 3 days from the calendar into my android app

Tags: android, android-activity, calendar, android-calendar, android-sdk-2.3

I'm trying to log all the events which are happening for 3 days from today in my activity. I'm getting the following errors. Please help.
My Code :

```
 public static long getStartOfDayInMillis() {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
        return calendar.getTimeInMillis();
    }


    public static ArrayList<String> readCalendarEvent(Context context) {
        Uri.Builder eventsUriBuilder;
        eventsUriBuilder = Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/events").buildUpon();
        ContentUris.appendId(eventsUriBuilder,getStartOfDayInMillis());
        ContentUris.appendId(eventsUriBuilder, getStartOfDayInMillis() + 3*(24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
        Uri eventsUri = eventsUriBuilder.build();
        Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver()
                .query(
                        eventsUri,
                        new String[] { "calendar_id", "title", "description",
                                "dtstart", "dtend", "eventLocation" }, null,
                        null, CalendarContract.Instances.DTSTART + " ASC");
        // fetching calendars name
        String CNames[] = new String[cursor.getCount()];

        // fetching calendars id
        nameOfEvent.clear();
        startDates.clear();
        endDates.clear();
        descriptions.clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < CNames.length; i++) {

            nameOfEvent.add(cursor.getString(1));
            startDates.add(getDate(Long.parseLong(cursor.getString(3))));
    //        endDates.add(getDate(Long.parseLong(cursor.getString(4))));
            descriptions.add(cursor.getString(2));
            CNames[i] = cursor.getString(1);
            cursor.moveToNext();

        }
        return nameOfEvent;
    }
```

I'm calling it to give logs of all the names of the events in the same Java class as..

```
results=   readCalendarEvent(MyCalendarActivity.this);
    for(int i=0;i< results.size();i++ )
        Log.d("results",results.get(i));
```

I'm getting the following errors :

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown URL content://com.android.calendar/events/1448821800000/1448908200000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are using wrong URL. Replace with this:

```
eventsUriBuilder = Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/instances/when").buildUpon();
```

Or:

```
eventsUriBuilder = CalendarContract.Instances.CONTENT_URI.buildUpon()
```